# import custom components package into vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, import, package, composer-php

I created a package with some of my vue components which needs to be shared between several apps.

In this package I wrote this line in composer.json :

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SharedApp\\SharedComponents\\": "src/components",
        }
    }
```

in my website, where I load the package, in a vue file, I import the template like this :

```
import NodeTree from '../../../vendor/website/shared-models/src/components/NodeTree.vue
```

It works but, there isn't proper way to do it?
like this :  `import NodeTree from 'SharedApp/SharedComponents/NodeTree.vue'`  ?
what am I missing?
thanks.

Comment: You could create an alias: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/aliases. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Answer (score 0):

Like Rwd said, a simple alias in the webpack/laravel mix do the work.

I tried it before without any success but it works now. I had to do something wrong before :)

I post the links again to reach them easily :

- [laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/aliases](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/aliases)
- [webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve)

Thanks.